# MongoDB - Getting records made by user

Tags: mongodb

I'm working with Mongodb, and was wondering on how to get records made by the user. In the below example I have to records each with different emails (createdBy), but how do I get the records by the current user logged in?

Schema result:

```
var resultSchema = new Schema({
test: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true},
status: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true},
date: { type: Date, required: true},
amount: { type: Number, required: true},
createdBy: { type: String, required: true},
});
```

Schema user:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
email: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true},
username: { type: String, required: true, lowercase: true},
password: { type: String, required: true}
});
```

Database:

```
"recipe": [
    {
        "_id": "5b7af572a1051b1b18aec627",
        "test": "asassdasdasd",
        "status": "waiting",
        "date": "2018-08-06T22:00:00.000Z",
        "amount": 2,
        "createdBy": "test@outlook.com",
        "__v": 0
    }
]

"recipe": [
    {
        "_id": "5b7af572a1051b1b18aec621",
        "test": "test2",
        "status": "waiting",
        "date": "2018-08-06T22:00:00.000Z",
        "amount": 2,
        "createdBy": "notTest@outlook.com",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I tried this, but this returns empty:

```
router.get('/userResults', (req, res) => {
Result.find({createdBy: req.body.createdBy}, (err, result) => {
  })

})
```

Comment: Make sure `req.body.createdBy` has a value there that is a string containing the email. You should also post your schema.

Comment: @Akrion I have updated the post with my schema. I printed the 'req.body.createdBy' and returns undefined

Comment: So that is the issue. req.body.createdBy should not be undefined.

Comment: @Akrion I have updated my post again. I have a user schema, so should I first get the email from the user schema, and then use it in the query?

Comment: You need an email to search for. How and from where it comes from that depends on how your app is setup but a simple test would be to just run your query with a hardcoded email to verify all works ... then provide the email however you see fit

Answer (score 0):

To say the user is logged in or not and to identify the user who is logged in, I am sure you have some mechanism to get the Email ID of the current user.
So ideally you should have access to the Email ID of the user who is logged in and making the API call.

- Provision a middleware to parse the email id from every request instead of making a Database call to check the user's email ID.
- Query : db.resultSchema.find({createdBy: parsed_email_id_from_api_request}

One way to do it using JWT is parse the token using a middleware and forwarding the email or any other relevant field to the request where you make the Database call to check the "results" collection.